# Can i extend the size of a listview dynamically in java code

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using a listview in a layout with a size- not in full size of layout.
Below the layout there are components like button.
I need the layout to get extended when more number of listitems adds dynamically.

I have kept the listview and buttons in scrollview.

Is there any attribute or option to make listview of variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have a listview inside a scrollview. Instead of having a listview you should add your items to a linearlayout, which will grow to accomodate the items and not enable the scrollbar within itself. This will solve your UI issue. You can set the onclickListeners in a for looop.

### Update

```
<ScrollView.....>
    <LinearLayout .....>
       <LinearLayout ..../> // this has your list items
       <Button .... /> // you can have a layout here if you have multiple buttons.
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your solution works good. So i need scroll view. Can i get scroll view in linear layout but the list should get extended. Any other idea or solution.

Comment: Put the whole layout in a another layout. then add that single layout to scrollview. Make scrollview the root.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ListView`'s `layout_height` value to `wrap_content`, and it will stretch to accomodate all the items' views in its adapter.